404 not found django media
Пишу сайт на django; появилась необходимость использования media.
Загрузил файлы в папку media, перед этим прописал
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

в settings,  и
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

в TimAnt32/urls (TimAnt32 - название проекта), но при переходе на /media/file.jpg вылезает 404;
помогите пожалуйста в решении этой проблемы

Попробуй добавить urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) в urls.py внутри приложения
